# Unknown type name in C when initializing variables

Tags: c

I am currently trying to code a program mainly for math class, but for some reason when I try to initialize variables in a function, I'm getting weird gcc errors. Keep in mind I'm a bit new at this, so sorry if it's a stupid question.

The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

int main() {
    int choice = 0;
    printf("ENTER CASE\n1 FOR SSS\n2 FOR SAS\n3 FOR SSA\n4 FOR AAS\n5 FOR ASSA\nWhich?\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    double s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area;
    if (choice = 1) {
        sss(s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area);
    }
    if (choice = 2) {
        sas(s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area);
    }
    if (choice = 3) {
        asa(s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area);
    }
    printf("S1 = %lf\nS2 = %lf\nS3 = %lf\nA1 = %lf\nA2 = %lf\nA3 = %lf\nArea = %lf\n", s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area);
}

// FUNCTIONS ----------------------------------------------------------
// SSS

double sss(double s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area) { 
    printf("Enter the three lengths\nExample 1,2,3\n\nEnter here: ");
    scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &s1, &s2, &s3);
    a1 = (180 / PI) * acos(((s2*s2) + (s3*s3) - (s1*s1)) / (2*s2*s3);
    a2 = (180 / PI) * acos(((s3*s3) + (s1*s1) - (s2*s2)) / (2*s3*s1);
    a3 = (180 / PI) * acos(((s1*s1) + (s2*s2) - (s3*s3)) / (2*s1*s2);
    area = (1/2) (s1*s2)*sin(a3 * (180 / PI);
    return s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area;
}

// SAS
double sas(double s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area) {
    printf("Enter S1,S2,D3\n\nS=side\nD3=degrees in angle 3\n");
    scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &s1, &s2, a3);
    s3 = sqrt(((s1*s1) + (s2*s2)) - ((2*s1*s2)*((180 / PI)cos(d3))));
    //after that, everything is copy and pasted on this part lol
    a1 = (180 / PI) * acos(((s2*s2) + (s3*s3) - (s1*s1)) / (2*s2*s3);
    a2 = (180 / PI) * acos(((s3*s3) + (s1*s1) - (s2*s2)) / (2*s3*s1);
    area = (1/2)(s1*s2) * sin(a3 * (180 / PI);

    return s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area;
}

// ASA
double asa(double s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area) {
    printf("Enter angles A1,A2 and side S3: \nex: 25,98,6\n\n::: ");
    scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &a1, &a2, &s3);
    a3 = 180 - (a1 + a2);
    // side s2 / (sin a2) = s3 / (sin a3)
    s2 = (((180 / PI) * (sin a2)) * s3) / ((180 / PI) * (sin a3));
    s1 = (((180 / PI) * (sin a1)) * s3) / ((180 / PI) * (sin a3));
    area = (1/2)(s1*s2) * sin(a3 * (180 / PI);

    return s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area;
}
```

GCC errors:

```
trianglesol.c:31:23: error: unknown type name ‘s2’
   31 |  double sas(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                       ^~
trianglesol.c:31:26: error: unknown type name ‘s3’
   31 |  double sas(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                          ^~
trianglesol.c:31:29: error: unknown type name ‘a1’
   31 |  double sas(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                             ^~
trianglesol.c:31:32: error: unknown type name ‘a2’
   31 |  double sas(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                                ^~
trianglesol.c:31:35: error: unknown type name ‘a3’
   31 |  double sas(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                                   ^~
trianglesol.c:31:38: error: unknown type name ‘area’
   31 |  double sas(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                                      ^~~~
trianglesol.c:44:23: error: unknown type name ‘s2’
   44 |  double asa(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                       ^~
trianglesol.c:44:26: error: unknown type name ‘s3’
   44 |  double asa(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                          ^~
trianglesol.c:44:29: error: unknown type name ‘a1’
   44 |  double asa(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                             ^~
trianglesol.c:44:32: error: unknown type name ‘a2’
   44 |  double asa(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                                ^~
trianglesol.c:44:35: error: unknown type name ‘a3’
   44 |  double asa(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
      |                                   ^~
trianglesol.c:44:38: error: unknown type name ‘area’
   44 |  double asa(double s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area) {
```

There's more errors but they're all the same thing.

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to prefix each and every argument with `double` like `double sss(double s1, double s2,  double s3,  double a1,  double a2, double a3,  double area)`

Comment: Yeah, this is just another argument against declaring variables with commas: *you can't do it in a function's parameter list.*  Always prefix your variable declaration with a type, and you'll never have this problem.

Comment: Your code looks a bit odd. There's  no point passing parameters s1, s2 and s3 to a function if the first thing it does is clobber them by fetching new values with `scanf()`. And anything of the form `return a, b, c` will just return the last value in the list. Learn how to use arrays.

Comment: In addition to having an incorrect function prototype, your comparisons are also incorrect.  They're actually assignments.  Do you know what `if (choice=1) ...` does?  It assigns `1` to `choice`, then executes the consequence code.  It then falls through and does the same for `2` and `3`.  Change `=` to `==`.

Comment: Instead of defining your own `PI`, you should use `M_PI` which is defined in `math.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,

```
 double sss(double s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area)
```

should be

```
double sss(double s1, double s2, doubel s3, double a1, double a2, double a3, double area)
```

i.e., you need to specify the data type for each of the parameters.

That said,

```
return s1,s2,s3,a1,a2,a3,area;
```

is the same as

```
return area;
```

because of the use of the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). If you want to return multiple values, use a structure type, where you can have values set of each member and then return the structure type variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are major problems in your code:

- `if (choice = 1)` sets `choice` to `1` before testing for a non zero expression... use `if (choice == 1)` instead.
- the variables `s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area` are updated in functions `sss`, `sas` and `asa`, so you should pack them in a structure and pass a pointer to this structure to these functions.
- `double sss(double s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area)` is a syntax error: you must specify the type of each argument individually as:

  ```
    double sss(double s1, double s2, double s3, double a1, double a2, double a3, double area)
  ```

but passing the variables would be passed by value so the function could not modify the values of the variables in the `main` function. Using a structure is a better solution.

- `area = (1/2) (s1*s2)*sin(a3 * (180 / PI);` is also a syntax error: multiplication is not implicit and there is a missing `)`. Furthermore `1/2` is an integer division with a value of `0`. Use double arithmetics and just divide the whole expression by `2.0`. The statement should be:

  ```
  area = 0.5 * s1 * s2 * sin(a3 * 180.0 / PI);
  ```
- `return s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area;` is **not** a syntax error, but for a very obscure reason for a beginner: the `,` here is an operator that ignores its left operand, so the statement is equivalent to `return area;`
- `scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &s1, &s2, a3);` has a missing `&` before `a3`. You should get a warning for this one, but it is a major error with undefined behavior.
- `s3 = sqrt(((s1*s1) + (s2*s2)) - ((2*s1*s2)*((180 / PI)cos(d3))));` has a missing `*`
- `area = (1/2)(s1*s2) * sin(a3 * (180 / PI);` has the same problems as above
- `s2 = (((180 / PI) * (sin a2)) * s3) / ((180 / PI) * (sin a3));`: missing `()` around function arguments for `sin`.
- the C trigonometric functions take arguments in radians, so you should multiply the `ax` variables by `(PI / 180.0)` instead of `(180.0 / PI)`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288

struct args { 
    double s1, s2, s3, a1, a2, a3, area;
};

void sss(struct args *p);  // functions must be declared or defined before use.
void sas(struct args *p);
void asa(struct args *p);

int main() {
    int choice = 0;
    struct args args = { 0 };
    printf("Enter case number:\n1 for SSS\n2 for SAS\n3 for SSA\n4 for AAS\n5 for ASSA\nWhich?\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &choice) == 1) {
        if (choice == 1) {
            sss(&args);
        } else
        if (choice == 2) {
            sas(&args);
        } else
        if (choice == 3) {
            asa(&args);
        } else
        if (choice == 4 || choice 5) {
            printf("unsupported choice\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("invalid choice\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("S1 = %f\nS2 = %f\nS3 = %f\nA1 = %f\nA2 = %f\nA3 = %f\nArea = %f\n",
               args.s1, args.s2, args.s3, args.a1, args.a2, args.a3, args.area);
    }
    return 0;
}

// FUNCTIONS ----------------------------------------------------------

// SSS
void sss(struct args *p) { 
    printf("Enter the three lengths\nExample 1,2,3\n\nEnter here: ");
    if (scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &p->s1, &p->s2, &p->s3) == 3) {
        p->a1 = (180.0 / PI) * acos(((p->s2 * p->s2) + (p->s3 * p->s3) - (p->s1 * p->s1)) / (2 * p->s2 * p->s3);
        p->a2 = (180.0 / PI) * acos(((p->s3 * p->s3) + (p->s1 * p->s1) - (p->s2 * p->s2)) / (2 * p->s3 * p->s1);
        p->a3 = (180.0 / PI) * acos(((p->s1 * p->s1) + (p->s2 * p->s2) - (p->s3 * p->s3)) / (2 * p->s1 * p->s2);
        p->area = 0.5 * p->s1 * p->s2 * sin(p->a3 * (PI / 180.0));
    }
}

// SAS
void sas(struct args *p) {
    printf("Enter S1,S2,D3\n\nS=side\nD3=degrees in angle 3\n");
    if (scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &p->s1, &p->s2, &p->a3) == 3) {
        p->s3 = sqrt(((p->s1 * p->s1) + (p->s2 * p->s2)) - ((2 * p->s1 * p->s2) * ((180.0 / PI) * cos(p->a3 * (PI / 180.0)))));
        //after that, everything is copy and pasted on this part lol
        p->a1 = (180.0 / PI) * acos(((p->s2 * p->s2) + (p->s3 * p->s3) - (p->s1 * p->s1)) / (2 * p->s2 * p->s3);
        p->a2 = (180.0 / PI) * acos(((p->s3 * p->s3) + (p->s1 * p->s1) - (p->s2 * p->s2)) / (2 * p->s3 * p->s1);
        p->area = 0.5 * p->s1 * p->s2 * sin(p->a3 * (PI / 180.0));
    }
}

// ASA
void asa(struct args *p) {
    printf("Enter angles A1,A2 and side S3: \nex: 25,98,6\n\n::: ");
    if (scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &p->a1, &p->a2, &p->s3) == 3) {
        p->a3 = 180.0 - (p->a1 + p->a2);
        // side s2 / (sin a2) = s3 / (sin a3)
        p->s2 = s3 * sin(p->a3 * (PI / 180.0)) / sin(p->a2 * (PI / 180.0));
        p->s1 = s3 * sin(p->a3 * (PI / 180.0)) / sin(p->a1 * (PI / 180.0));
        p->area = 0.5 * p->s1 * p->s2 * sin(p->a3 * (PI / 180.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: @wildplasser: oops, forgot that obvious one.

Comment: Using `else if` would make more sense here (or a `switch` statement).